# Integrate of simple equation but is not solving!

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, function-construction, variable, simplex

I have this simple integral but I don't know why Mathematica can't solve it?!

FullSimplify[Integrate[x/(-x^2 + a x + b)^(1/2), {x, Sqrt[b], Sqrt[R^2 + b]},Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Include the assumption that `R` is real.

```
Assuming[{a > 0, b > 0, Element[R, Reals]},
 Integrate[x/(-x^2 + a x + b)^(1/2), {x, Sqrt[b], Sqrt[R^2 + b]}] // 
  FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We can test the result by uses Newton-Leibniz formula.

```
f = Integrate[x/(-x^2 + a x + b)^(1/2), x];
expr2 = (f /. x -> Sqrt[R^2 + b]) - (f /. x -> Sqrt[b])
expr1 = Integrate[
  x/(-x^2 + a x + b)^(1/2), {x, Sqrt[b], Sqrt[R^2 + b]}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, R > 0}]
FullSimplify[expr1 == expr2, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, R > 0}]
```

> True